# If cell contains specific string, limit the input length in another cell

Tags: excel

How can I limit the input length of text in a cell if another cell contains a specific string?

i.e. if cell A1 contains "DEV", then limit the input length of cell B1 to 4 characters.

Comment: What do you mean by limit? Do you want to show a message if the value entered in B1 is too long? Where do you want to show the message?

Comment: Let, A1 = DEV, B1 = blablabla. Then C1 = if(A1="DEV", left(B1,4), B1). C1 will be equal to "blab". Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data validation to do this.

Select the range you want to apply this to.
Under Data, choose "Data Validation"
Select "Text Length" and "less than or equal to"
Enter the following formula in the "Maximum" box:
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("DEV",A1)),255,4)
Change "FIND" to "SEARCH" if you don't want it to be case sensitive.

EDIT: for clarification, select the range you want to limit the entry length of, then select "Data Validation". Also, "A1" be the first cell adjacent to the range you're applying the limit to. So if you have a header row and you want to apply the limit to column B for 5 rows, "A1" should be changed to "A2" and you would select B2 to B6 before proceeding.

[image: Data Validation Menu]

Comment: Glad to help. Just one thing, you might want to change my "999" to "255" which is the actual cell length maximum in Excel. I doubt it would cause any issue, but you never know. (In fact, I edited the answer, just in case.)